# Проблема с xDeBug + PHPStorm + Apache2 + Ubuntu с альтернативными версиями PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpstorm, apache2, xdebug

Использую несколько альтернативных версий php. Так же использую PHPSTORM. 
К примеру переключился на версию 7.0 в файле etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini

```
[xdebug] 
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

В PHPStorm - language level 7.0 , Cli Interpretet 7.033

При попытке задебажить скрипт Шторм падает на первый бейкпоинт а после просмотра следующего он просто отдаёт Connected и зависает браузерное окно.
Ребят подскажите может кто-то сталкивался. Или хотя бы как-то логировать что случается xDebug.

Comment: Просмотрите примеры статей от JetBrains по [настройке отладки для PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov , пробовал как раз по этой статьи делать, но результат тот же. Первый брейк поинт и всё . Спасибо

Comment: Проверьте маппинг путей к файлам, [в которых вы ставите брейки](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307218/map-one-directory-path-to-another-in-phpstorm)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov , я не подключаю в файл с брейк поинтами не каких других файлов , просто вывод на страницу и присвоение нескольких переменных.

Comment: Вы уверены что исполнение вообще доходит до ваших брейкпойнтов, которые не включаются?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov , брейкпоинт до начала дебага горит как кружок после как галочка в кружке и бедаг попадает на первый из них.